How to estimate the inverse of a non-invertible matrix?
So I'm working on a machine learning problem where my solution requires taking the inverse of a matrix at some point. The problem is that this matrix is sometimes non-invertible. In theory the the solution works well if we assume that we can always solve for this inverse but in practice this has been a problem.
So just to give you a simple toy example. Let the matrix A be given by
\begin{pmatrix}
24 & 24 \\
-24 & -24
\end{pmatrix}
And let the matrix L be given by
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
I am trying to solve for the following. $(A^\top A \circ L)^{-1}$
Where $\circ$ is defined by $(A \circ B)_{i,j} = A_{i,j}B_{i,j}$
$L$ is always constant, but $A$ is not. $A$ changes on every training iteration, so its hard for me to pinpoint any properties to this whole equation.
There are two techniques I have at my hand at the moment to try and 'estimate' or solve for this inverse when it doesn't exist.
The first and slightly naive way, is to add some noise to one of the columns of $A$. So for example I would add 0.01 to the first column of $A$. I would keep doing this until I am able to take the inverse.
The second way is to clip the minimum Eigen value to a small positive constant $\epsilon = 10^{-5}$ (This value can be smaller or larger). So essentially convert the matrix $(A^\top A \circ L)^{-1}$, which is PSD, into a PD matrix. This doesn't always guarantee invertibility, but even when it works and allows for the inverse, the solutions I get are sometimes zero which isn't making sense to me and practically useless.
So now, with all this said. Is there a smarter way to go about this problem? Maybe something a bit more rigorous. I'm mainly concerned with practicality at this point.

What are you going to do with this inverse matrix after? Depending on this, you may want different approaches. One more or less standard is to use pseudoinverse matrix instead of inverse.

Well, the inverse of this matrix is then multiplied by another matrix to compute a vector of values that will be used in the following iteration of training.

I think you can use the thought of ridge regression. Using $(A^TA+\epsilon I)*L $ instead of $(A^TA)*L$
